# Service Fabric: local cluster gives 403 Access forbidden

Tags: azure-service-fabric

i have added orchestration container support to my existing asp.net MVC web application. when i deploy to local cluster and accessing the application cluster url i am getting following error

403- Forbidden: Access is Denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you have supplied.

Service manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="ManagementPkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType.
         The UseImplicitHost attribute indicates this is a guest service. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="ManagementType" UseImplicitHost="true" />
  </ServiceTypes>

  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <!-- Follow this link for more information about deploying Windows containers to Service Fabric: https://aka.ms/sfguestcontainers -->
      <ContainerHost>
        <ImageName>webtimesheetmanagement:dev</ImageName>
      </ContainerHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <!-- Pass environment variables to your container: -->
    <!--
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="VariableName" Value="VariableValue"/>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
    -->
  </CodePackage>

  <!-- Config package is the contents of the Config directoy under PackageRoot that contains an
       independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service. -->
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0" />

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to
           listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with
           replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
      <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ManagementTypeEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8131" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

when i deploy to local cluster or run locally

http://localhost:8131/

it gives me 403 forbidden error.

do we need to change any configuration?

please help

Comment: Could you navigate to your app in the Service Fabric Explorer (http://localhost:19080). Here you would see the endpoint that was assigned to your application.

Comment: i am getting same error when i use the endpoint url as well. :(

Comment: Can you update post with some screenshot of your service from Service Fabric Explorer?

Comment: hi.. did u find a solution to this

Comment: i was not able to resolve...